# how to get difference between two consecutive row value for the same column value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id    height    month
276     64       4
276     64       5
276     55       6
298     70       4
298     61       5
299     74       4
351     63       4
351     54       5
351     67       6
```

For the same id column : For the increasing value of month column there must be increasing value, or equal to the previous value, in height column, select all those rows which doesn't satisfy this condition.
I mean to say select row number:= 3,5,8

Comment: Did you write some sql?

Comment: not even understand the question very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using correlated subquery:

```
select *
from t
where height < (
        select height
        from t t2
        where t.id = t2.id
            and t.month > t2.month
        order by month desc limit 1
        )
```

Produces:

```
id  height  month
276 55      6
298 61      5
351 54      5
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/NOKSPS33975)

#### How it works:

`LIMIT` is used here to get the height for last month. It is used in combo with `order by` clause and produces first row based on the given order. In our case, we've filtered out month greater than or equal to current month for current id, sorted in order of descending months and take the height from the first row using `limit` - effectively creating a partitioned `lag` functionality present in others databases.

Comment: thanks, everything is just fine..but why did you use 'limit 1'.?.plz explain.